# Storing and reading encrypted strings from file in Python

Tags: python, pycrypto

I'm using AES (from PyCrypto) to encrypt passwords and store it in a file. The format of the file is:

```
user:username
key:<encrypted key>
```

And this is the method I used for encryption:

```
BLOCK_SIZE = ..
PADDING = ..
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
cipher = AES.new("abcdefgh12345678")

encrypted_key = EncodeAES(cipher, 'ABC123')
```

Now, how do I read the key from the file for decrypting it? If I use line.split(":"), wouldn't it cause problem if the encrypted key itself had ":" as a character?

Is there any way to avoid ":" while encrypting it? Or is there a better way for storing the keys? I cannot use hashing as I need the key for some other functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, how do I read the key from the file for decrypting it? If I use line.split(":"), wouldn't it cause problem if the encrypted key itself had ":" as a character?

Of course it would—that's why exactly [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) has a second, optional argument `max_split`:

```
key, value = line.split(':', 1)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
key, _, value = line.partition(':')
```

The difference between the two is what happens when there isn't a colon at all; the former will return one element, giving you a `ValueError` from trying to unpack it into two variables, while the latter will just give you an empty `value`.

---

However, it's worth noting that if you're using Base 64, `:` is never going to appear in the first place. The only character used by Base 64 are `A`-`Z`, `a`-`z`, `0`-`9`, `+`, and `/`. There are some Base 64 variants, and maybe one of them does use `:`, but the standard version, as applied by Python's `base64` module, does not.

Comment: oh that's right. Sorry, I didn't realize that. Lack of sleep. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the username in the first line and password in the second line, as the following

```
 username
 p4ssw0rd
```

This way you won't need to do this sort of things.

Although the best solution is to store these kind of things in the database.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be in key:value format. I have multiple attributes for each user, and they can be in any order.

Comment: Then I seriously suggest to use a real format. It's reaaallllyyyy easy with Python e.g. JSON. Much less code than parsing stuff manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain how many splits are performed:

```
>>> line="key:foo:bar:baz"
>>> line.split(":", 1)
['key', 'foo:bar:baz']
```

As long as you know the fieldname doesn't have a ':' in it, this should work fine.